# Choosing 26 of 52 cards, reciprocal probability.

Tags: probability

Here we have a deck of $52$ cards numbered $1$ thru $52$ (integers only).  We randomly select $26$ of those $52$ cards (without replacement).  Each card is equiprobable. The task is to find out how many hands have the sum of the reciprocals of the chosen ranks exactly equal to $2$. $52 \choose 26$ is quite large (about $496$ trillion) so a straightforward count might not be possible on some computers in a reasonable amount of time.  $26$ happens to be very convenient though since there are $26$ letters in the alphabet, thus allowing me to run nested loops with single letter names of a,b,c.. .z.

I am interested to see what "pruning" and rank exclusions can be done to this problem cuz this is a much larger state space than $16$ billion (if choosing only $10$ cards from a deck of $52$).  About $31,000$ times larger.

A slight hint/head start:  The maximum possible sum is about $3.85442$ and the minimum possible sum is about $0.6836$.  This is one reason why I chose $2$ as it appears it is possible.  I don't even know yet if there is a single solution but I would suspect there are many, although a very small percentage.

Comment: Note that this is difficult for me to solve since I use an interpreted language and it will require about 300+ lines of code and with 26 nested loops, there is more chance of error.   People out there have other tools they can use to try to solve this.  I think it is a good question for state space pruning/management.  A straightforward count, while possible, might take a good while even using a compiled language.  Mathematically, it will be interesting to see what ranks can be thrown out                to speed things up.  Also splitting this into $2$ groups of $13$ is not so easy either.

Comment: If you multiply through by $52!$, then this problem becomes a subset sum (type) problem.  This is known to be NP-hard in general, but perhaps it is easier in this case.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Can you elaborate please?

Comment: A variation of Fibonacci's greedy algorithm for Egyptian fractions should solve this in a short amount of time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm_for_Egyptian_fractions

Comment: You can reduce the search space considerably with some analysis.  You can exclude any prime greater than $26$, as well as $49, 27, 32$ as you can't get rid of their factors in the denominator.  Now you know you need more than half, so loop over the ones excluded.  Quitting when the sum gets too large or there aren't enough choices left to make it large enough can help as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't going to answer, but I just got a new compiler and I also wanted to show the original questioner how he could use arrays to make his life easier.

Elementary number theory as remarked here and in the companion thread allows us to eliminate the set $E=\{13,17,19,23,25,27,29,31,32,34,37,38,41,43,44,46,47,49,50,51\}$ and also dictates that the sets $C_{11}=\{11,22,33\}$, $C_{13}=\{26,39,52\}$, and $C_{16}=\{16,48\}$ are each either all in the set of cards in a successful trial or all absent.

This leaves the set $F=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15,18,20,21,24,28,30,35,36,40,42,45\}$ of $24$ free, or at least less constrained cards. We have to include at least one of the constrained sets, $C_{11}$, $C_{12}$, or $C_{16}$ because there aren't enough cards in $F$. The sums of the reciprocals of the elements of $F$, $C_{11}$, $C_{12}$, and $C_{16}$ are $\frac{85}{24}$, $\frac16$, $\frac1{12}$, and $\frac1{12}$ respectively.

$F\cup C_{16}$ is just big enough, but the sum is $\frac{87}{24}$, much too large. Also $F\cup C_{11}$ and $F\cup C_{13}$ sum to $\frac{89}{24}$ and $\frac{87}{24}$, so even if you remove card $1$ to get to $26$ cards the sum will be too large.

$F\cup C_{11}\cup C_{16}$ sums to $\frac{91}{24}$, so we would have to remove $3$ items from $F$ with total value $\frac{43}{24}$. Since $\frac12+\frac13+\frac14=\frac{13}{12}<\frac{43}{24}$, card $1$ must be removed. Also since $\frac11+\frac13+\frac14=\frac{19}{12}<\frac{43}{24}$, also card $2$ must be removed, but now we are at $\frac7{24}$ with only one card left.

$F\cup C_{13}\cup C_{16}$ is eliminated from consideration in a similar fashion.

$F\cup C_{11}\cup C_{13}$ sums to $\frac{91}{24}$ as well, but now we have $4$ cards to work with. Once again, magnitude considerations dictate that cards $1$ and $2$ are destined for removal, but now after doing so we find that we need to arrive at $\frac{91}{24}-2-\frac11-\frac12=\frac7{24}$ in two cards. Since the denominator is divisible by $8$, one of the other cards removed must be $8$, $24$, or $40$. We find that $\frac18+\frac16=\frac1{24}+\frac14=\frac1{40}+\frac4{15}=\frac7{24}$, so we have two solutions:

$\{3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,18,20,21,22,24,26,28,30,33,35,36,39,40,42,45,52\}$

and

$\{3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,15,18,20,21,22,26,28,30,33,35,36,39,40,42,45,52\}$

That leaves the set $F\cup C_{11}\cup C_{13}\cup C_{16}$. Again magnitude considerations eliminate card $1$ from consideration so we have to find $5$ more cards from $F$ that sum to $\frac{31}{8}-2-\frac11=\frac78$. Now, patience and elementary number theory could clean this up in an hour or so by hand, but that would be a long post. Instead I offer a brute force program that searches the remaining space of ${23\choose 5} = 33649$ possibilities.

I create arrays for the sets $F$, $C_{11}$, $C_{13}$, and $C_{16}$, then to hold the reciprocals of the cards in $F$. Then I compute the sum of the reciprocals of $F\cup C_{11}\cup C_{13}\cup C_{16}-\{1\}$ and subtract $2$ so I know what my target to shoot for with the next $5$ cards to be removed is. Loop through all possibilities, counting up and printing out all solutions. Since roundoff error is going to be less than $50$ ulps and the biggest real error is $\frac1{2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7}=\frac1{2520}$ cutting off potential solutions at $100$ ulps definitely separates true solutions from spurious ones.

The program prints out $30$ solutions, so along with the $2$ obtained by hand, this is consistent with @Giovanni Resta's results.

```
program cards26
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: dp = kind([double precision::])
   integer i1,i2,i3,i4,i5
   integer, parameter :: cards(24) = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14, &
      15,18,20,21,24,28,30,35,36,40,42,45]
   integer, parameter :: c11(3) = [11,22,33]
   integer, parameter :: c13(3) = [26,39,52]
   integer, parameter :: c16(2) = [16,48]
!   integer, parameter :: exclude(20) = [13,17,19,23,25,27,29,31, &
!      32,34,37,38,41,43,44,46,47,49,50,51]
   real(dp),parameter :: reciprocals(size(cards)) = 1.0_dp/cards
   real(dp) x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
   integer N

   x0 = sum(1.0_dp/cards)+sum(1.0_dp/c11)+sum(1.0_dp/c13)+ &
      sum(1.0_dp/c16)-2-1
   write(*,*) 'Target = ', x0
   N = 0
   do i1 = 2,size(cards)-4
      x1 = reciprocals(i1)
      do i2 = i1+1,size(cards)-3
         x2 = x1+reciprocals(i2)
         do i3 = i2+1,size(cards)-2
            x3 = x2+reciprocals(i3)
            do i4 = i3+1,size(cards)-1
               x4 = x3+reciprocals(i4)
               do i5 = i4+1,size(cards)
                  x5 = x4+reciprocals(i5)
                  if(abs(x5-x0) < 100*epsilon(1.0_dp)) then
                     N = N+1
                     write(*,'(i4,1x,26(i2,1x),f19.17)') N, &
                        pack(cards,[(all(cards(N)/=cards([1,i1,i2,i3, &
                           i4,i5])),N=1,size(cards))]),c11,c13,c16,x5
                  end if
               end do
            end do
         end do
      end do
   end do
end program cards26
```

Comment: Wow nice work.   I did not take an elementary number theory class in college nor did we do any type of card simulation type programs.  I do this type of stuff for fun.   It is very interesting how mathematical analysis can take a problem that  has such a huge state space, and filter it down to something much more manageable.  Someone that knew nothing about math but could program would have to write 26 nested loops and (let 'er rip).  Likely it would take  many hours even of a fast computer.  I will try 26 empty nested loops but with the excluded ranks and count up how many hands that is.

Answer (score 5):

If I did not make some horrible mistake, there are 32 solutions.

For example,
$$
2=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{
   10}+\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{18}+
\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{22}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{26}+\frac{1}{30}
   +\frac{1}{33}+\frac{1}{35}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{39}+\frac{1}{40}+\frac{1
   }{42}+\frac{1}{45}+\frac{1}{48}+\frac{1}{52}
$$

Actually this problem is easier than previous problem, after some initial pruning. I just analyzed 6287724 configurations.

For each prime $p\ge7$ I checked which combinations of sums of reciprocals of multiples of $p$ could lead to a fraction where the prime $p$ does not appear at the denominator.Since $7\cdot11>52$ I did not combine multiples of different primes greater than $7$.

For example, for $p=11$ there is only $\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{22}+\frac{1}{33}=\frac{1}{6}$.

for $p=13$ there is only $\frac{1}{26}+\frac{1}{39}+\frac{1}{52}=\frac{1}{12}$,

and for $p=7$ there are $9$ sums, like $\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{42}=\frac{1}{6}$ or
$
\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{21}+\frac{1}{28}+\frac{1}{42}=\frac{1}{4}.
$

The remaining numbers, once you take away the multiples of all the primes larger or equal to $7$, are only $24$:
$$
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 27, 30, 32, 
36, 40, 45, 48, 50
$$

So, for each possible choice of a sum for prime $7$, one for prime $11$ and one for prime $13$ (among which the void sum) I selected all the possible combinations of the $24$ numbers above to have a total of $26$ numbers, and I checked the sums.

For example, if I selected for $13$ nothing, for $11$ the only possible sum ($3$ terms) and for $7$ the shown sum with $4$ terms, I have to check $${24\choose26-3-4}={24\choose19}=657800
$$
combinations. All in all the combinations to be checked were 6287724, so instead of a program in C I used a little program in Mathematica, that is much slower but can construct directly all the subsets of a given set.

The first and last solutions, lexicographically, are
$$
2, 4, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 33,
35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 48, 52
$$
and
$$
3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 
33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 52
$$

Comment: How do you know only $32$ for sure?

Comment: Easier cuz you had practice with the first one and got good at it?  What if this was the first problem instead?  32 seems low for that many card combinations.  32 out of 496 trillion is a minuscule amount percentagewise.

Comment: In my simulation program (which I will try tonight), I set up the loops for all possible card values initially, but then within the loops, I check for the excluded cards, thus bypassing the body of the code in the loop if it is one of the excluded cards.  Some languages (such a Ada), allow you to specify a "skip loop" where you can go something like 1-10, 12, 15, 17-22 ...  .  In other words, you can loop thru ranges (such as 1 thru 10), then skip to 12 (skipping over 11)...  Not sure which is more efficient, having the language handle it or coding it manually in a general purpose language.

Comment: My first attempt will just be to run empty loops (no code in body) with the excluded ranks to see how many hands it tells me I need to scan.   I thin kit will be a large number without any short circuit checks for "way" over 2 or "way" under 2, but it will be start.  I could also clone my code for the 10 card solution and make it handle 26 cards but that has to be done very carefully cuz of all the optimizations.  I could easily make a mistake and the mushroom cloud will go up.

Answer (score 0):

Well so far all I got are the $26$ nested loops set up as if they were going to iterate all of the $496$ trillion card combinations but then when I exclude the  $20$ cards, it tells me $906,192$ card combinations.  This is simply $52-20 \choose 26$.  The time it takes to go thru the empty loops is about $6.5$ minutes so that is reasonable.  So my next step will be to insert the code to check if the sum is exactly equal to $2$ and count them up to see if I get $32$.

Also, if I exclude $1$ as the lowest numbered card , I get $169,911$ hands in  $2$ min $40$ sec.

I tried running my program checking for the sum of $2$ but I did not get $32$ so I have to figure out why.